# How to display programmaticaly default user picture?

Tags: users

I want to display programmatically default user picture if the user is not uploaded any. For that I have written code php code but its displaying user uploaded user picture correctly but not the one default when user doesn't upload his/her own. How to do that? help me.

```
$user = user_load($user->uid);
$account = user_load($user->uid);
print theme(
    'image_style',
    array( 'account' =>$user,
      'style_name' => 'x-small', 
     // 'path' =>!empty($user->picture->uri)?$user->picture->uri:variable_get('user_picture_default'),
      'path' =>!empty($user->picture->uri)?$user->picture->uri:variable_get('user_picture_default',''),
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => 'avatar' 
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why programmatically drupal provide this functionality out of the box. 
Go to Configuration >> People >> Account Settings. Under personalisation section you can provide the url of the default picture and can select the image style to use for the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its very straight forward. If you want to add a default picture then go ahead and add the picture from the admin page as the other answer suggested. Programmatically, 
The default picture is loaded via the variable `user_picture_default`. 
So you can do,

```
$user = user_load($uid);
print theme('image_style', array('path' => $user->picture->uri, 'style_name' => '<image-style>'));

if (!empty($user->picture)) {
  print theme('image_style', array('path' => $user->picture->uri, 'style_name' => 'CUSTOM_STYLE'));
}
else {
  $custom_default_image_path = 'public://default_image.png';
  print theme('image_style', array('path' => variable_get('user_picture_default', $custom_default_image_path), 'style_name' => 'CUSTOM_STYLE'));
}
```

However, you can also make the default image theme dependent/independent via the [hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign a default picture path in Account settings in the drupal admin as described by Mutant Mahesh .

Then you can use this code to print picture anywhere in your code

```
<?php
global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid);
  print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user));
?>
```

Hope it will work for you.